# ORA-08103: object no longer exists - insert query fails

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I'm encountering this error multiple times, but it appears to be random.
I perform an INSERT query where I attempt to insert a BLOB file into a designated table.
I do not know if there's a connection between the BLOB and the error.
Worth mentioning that the table is partitioned.

Here is the complete query:

```
INSERT INTO COLLECTION_BLOB_T   
(OBJINST_ID, COLINF_ID, COLINF_PARTNO, BINARY_FILE_NAME, BINARY_FILE_SIZE, BINARY_FILE)  
VALUES (:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, EMPTY_BLOB());
```

This is the only INSERT/UPDATE into this table in the entire application.
So I doubt that any other query is locking it, and the error is not about a locked resource.

What can be the cause?
As I've mentioned, this appears to occur randomly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything in the alert log when you see this error?

Comment: No errors in RDBMS alert log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is partitioned as I've mentioned, so between midnight - 3:00AM the partitioned changes and this under some instances the error occurs.